# EQ'ing ADR to match Dialogue

Tags: adr

So this is a question that has been around since the dawn of post production.

How to get the best possible match to surrounding dialogue with ADR. Does anyone have any top secret tips?

Obviously you can buy plugins which analyse the frequencies in the original dialogue and then apply it to your ADR but those cost money!

.....

Do you just play around with channel strip eq until you get something similar?

EQ can only do so much as the performance needs to match; but I can't ever seem to match remotely tricky ones. The standard ADR I can match with slight eq but if I get a tricky section like the actors being in a tiny room, or somewhere not completely standard; then I struggle to know where to begin!

Answer (score 2):

ADR matching is really about the performance. Its incredibly hard to make it match if the performance isn't right. There are analyzers you can find for free or come with your Daw to help you understand what your hearing frequency wise but EQ is really only part of the equation. From a technical standpoint Eq is important obviously but so is having some proper room tone fill and consistent reverb.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with coaxmw on this - and would add that good mic placement is better than post-EQ or reverb in getting ADR and dialog to match.

In my mind, the #1 priority is performance, followed by mic placement, and from there hopefully you won't need to do too much post-processing.  Getting the first two right will simplify the ADR and production mix considerably.