# How to match a talent voice between different takes?

Tags: equalization, adr

I record educational videos and often I have to re-record voices because of the excessive environment noise or simply because of poor performance. Since I'm not working with professional talents (including myself), from one take to the next the voice pitch can be (very) different. I don't necessarily notice that while recording, but, when editing, the transition between two takes is clearly audible.

For now, to solve that issue I work with the equalizer--but this is time-consuming and too often the result is far from being optimal. So is there any other option to match ADR voice with the original performance? Or do I just need to improve my "equalizing" skills?

## Edit:

Here is a sample: http://www.chicoree.fr/pub/Audio/DIFFERENT-TONE.wav

- take 1

  > *as you can see, that text is made of*
- take 2

  > *three logicaaaal lines*

It seems to me the voice on the second take is clearly "higher" than on the first one.

---

<sub>Related to [EQ'ing ADR to match Dialogue](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/30165/eqing-adr-to-match-dialogue), but in my case, this is the talent voice that "change" between the takes. Not the environment.</sub>

Comment: As mentioned in the link you provide, 'ADR matching is really about the performance. Its incredibly hard to make it match if the performance isn't right.'.

Comment: Indeed @audionuma. But as far as I understand that answer, it is about matching the ADR "cabin" tone with the original room tone. Here I'm really talking about two takes recorded in the same place, with the same talent, but where, despite apparently ideal conditions, the voice is not consistent between the takes. But I assume this might lead to the same conclusion...

Comment: Bonjour ! Can you provide us some (short) examples of two such takes that are so different ? Unfortunately, the quote does apply to your case, it's a talent issue.

Comment: @audionuma I've edited the question with a link to a sample file (of my own voice--since I'm affected by the same plague;) I probably can work my own voice placement. But it is hard to ask that to random speakers I meet for only one day, that's why I was looking for a "fix"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equalization will not affect pitch perception in any way. Your issue as you have correctly identified, is primarily one of direction, rather than being technical.

You can use pitch manipulation tools but not to a massive extent as it will quickly become noticable.

When directing these performances, try to ensure that there is a consistent level of energy between each performance - this will help with pitch consistency.

Comment: In fact, I don't know exactly _what_ is different in the voice between two takes. I assumed it was the voice envelope, but you are right, it might be the pitch. I will provide a sample.

Comment: I've edited the question with a link to a sample file

Comment: It sounds to me that the performance energy was completely different between the two takes. This results in an audible difference in the pitch/energy of the two performances. Your issue is one of direction and ensuring that the performer maintains consistent energy between readings. If they are unable to do this, then the issue needs to be dealt with in the edit, by not editing together takes with markedly different energy levels.

Comment: To add, if you are recording dubs, instead of replacing half of a sentence, just replace the whole sentence. Punching in in the middle of a sentence will almost always sound unnatural.